# Implementing Robots.txt

Tags: 2013

What is the best way to implement robots.txt in SDL Tridion?

Is it necessary to keep in the root folder or can we put it in another folder in the site and do a redirect so the Google Crawler can follow and fetch it?

Comment: I think it's implied, but just to be, this is *with* Tridion?

Comment: Yes - it's implied. Otherwise the question would be off-topic!

Answer (score 9):

Yes , it is necessary to keep robots.txt  in the root folder of your website. You can not put it in any subdirectory of the website for example –

http://www.yourdomain.com/robots.txt is a valid location.

And

http://www.yourdomain.com/home/robots.txt is not valid location.

you can not put this in a subdirectory because bots only check for this file in the root of the domain.

Answer (score 8):

If you ask me, I would never suggest keeping something in SDL Tridion CMS which is not a content (please explore basic CMS concept to learn what really is a content), as CMS is meant for effectively keeping your content and not everything which is being required by your site.

I would suggest the deployment of robot.txt should be out of the CMS, if you have a requirement of keeping or managing robot.txt in CMS, please re-verify the requirement - keep in mind CMS is meant to manage only the content.

I have even seen people keeping DLLs in Tridion and publishing as multimedia component to cut on the deployment - To me it is absolute non-sense.

Golden Words (I learn from a CMS expert) - CMS is not everything in your website or application, it is a very small part of the architecture of your application.

In the extreme case, even if you want to keep robot.txt in CMS, you have to keep it at the root of your website and you may follow one of the following process:

1. Keep robot.txt as a multimedia component and us the C# TBB as explained in earlier post to directly publish it to the root of your website
2. Create a Schema -> Component containing content of robot.txt -> corresponding CT to generate plain text -> corresponding PT to out put as robot.txt -> A page at root structure group.

All comes with their pros & cons.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Very much agree with that, I think too often a CMS is seen as a deployment tool which it really is not (apart from all you can do). But with that said, when people do make it a requirement that a robots.txt is managed inside the CMS, then it is good to know how you can do it.

Comment: Point taken, updating the answer :)

Comment: I don't see why you shouldn't deploy your robots.txt from the CMS. You can argue that it's not content (I'd disagree) but even then it doesn't get us very far. Have you got a concrete reason why it's a bad idea?

Comment: +1 for the point that a CMS isn't meant for code publishing. @DominicCronin, I think the assumption here is robots.txt is (always) owned by development. If we break it down like other page and content types, maybe it's *almost always* managed by development. Giving authors a way to manage (maybe non-critical) website "configuration" could be a valid CMS use case. Not all users need access, nor do you need to make it a wide open text box.

Comment: @Dominica Cronin: Consider following points:

(1) 
In Software Architecture, there is a principle called - SOLID Principle - where S stands for Single Responsibility (a class a supposed to do only a single well defined responsibility or function), you can extend it further to Components level where CMS is a component of your entire architecture and is defined to manage the content.

(2)
Consider a scenario when you are going to a scenic picnic and planning to capture few scene, which option will you choose - A DSLR camera or a mobile phone with camera?

Comment: (3) If you have a budget or time constraints (like you can not own a DSLR or do not have time to go to store and buy) or your requirement are quite precise (like you will only capture still objects in Day light and can live with low quality) you can go ahead and have your implementation in CMS (you can refer any of the above methods mentioned in the answer)

Comment: @PankajGaur I'm aware of many software architecture principles. You still haven't given a reason why we shouldn't manage robots.txt in the CMS

Comment: @AlvinReyes Should I stop publishing code out of the CMS? Now you're being silly. Should I stop publishing assets that are owned by development? Of course not. The point of a WCMS is that it allows you to manage both those concerns, but differently. If all I want to publish is content, I'll use FTP!

Comment: @DominicCronin ok, so not all "code", but +1 to Pankaj's point on managing dll and jars with better tools. I don't necessarily agree code components or multimedia would be the best in-Tridion options (or that CMS only handles "content"). I do think this discussion would be better on Linked-In, Twitter, or even the forum. By [Midas Rule](http://midasrule.blogspot.com/2013/01/what-is-midas-rule.html), I started [a poll](http://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=47490&type=member&item=229838286&qid=f42b1bb8-d68c-4d8a-88e7-4bd12cc66336&trk=group_most_recent_rich-0-b-ttl&goback=%2Egmr_47490)! :-)

Comment: Poll is gone. I have a different reason for not managing robots.txt in the CMS--I updated my answer.

Comment: Re: maintaining code and "non-content" assets in Tridion, I'm curious to know what are some of the disadvantages based on your experiences with managing tridion based websites? Assuming that jars, dlls and config files updates can be automated using powershell/coreservices.

Comment: Regarding managing code in Tridion - How to you maintain/manage this code in the case when you left the project and someone else want to take over?
Regarding Non-Content assets - I would prefer to use a system for which it is meant to be used to be on the safer side and not worrying while upgrading it say 5 years down the line and wondering if I have to change my deployment strategy?

Answer (score 4):

If developer-owned, let development handle `robots.txt` file as Pankaj suggests.

But authors *could* control it with a Category:

**Robots**
 [ ] Disallow

- Set Robots on Page and/or Structure Group Metadata.
- If different across Publications, move this field to a Component for the page.
- Consider generating the file similar to navigation approaches

If you prefer per-page control, instead use Keywords like:

(x) Everything (INDEX,FOLLOW) [Selected by Default]
( ) Just this page (INDEX,NOFOLLOW)
( ) Just links (NOINDEX,FOLLOW)
( ) None (NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW)

Template the actual text to `<META NAME="ROBOTS">`.

*I feel managing `robots.txt` in the CMS doesn't add much business value and someone might forget it's managed.*

**Giving editors per-page control in a business-friendly way, with an assumed default, might be more worth the effort.**

Comment: I completely agree with this.  "Generating the file similar to navigation approaches" (rather than being editable in a Component) would also ensure that the robots.txt file has the correct syntax.

Comment: You know it's a post by Alvin when you see simulated check-boxes or radio buttons :D

Comment: SEO-friendly and accessible? Or maybe I'm lazy. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There are probably hundreds of ways to implement things like robots.txt.

Let me start by asking... How would you do it *without* Tridion? Furthermore, does the robots.txt file need to be content managed?

My guess is that without a CMS, you would probably write a text file in your preferred text editor, add it to your source control system and deploy it out to your site. This approach is still perfectly valid. After all, why do authors/editors need to modify the robots.txt? How often do you intend to change it?

If you still think you need to store it in the CMS, read on...

You could store it in Tridion as a multimedia component and publish it to the root structure group using a .Net based TBB and one of the `engine.addBinary()` methods. There is a TBB that already exists somewhere on [Tridion World](https://sdltridionworld.com/) that publishes multimedia components from a known folder to a matching structure group (see [AppStore](https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/set-of-useful-template-building-blocks/688/)).

Another option is to store the content of your robots.txt file using a very simple schema, i.e. a single multi-line plain text field or similar and then output it using a simple page and component template that outputs the text field. This setup can be using for writing other plain text assets, like small chunks of JavaScript code into a page, for example, but I'd advise you to hide this schema from editors (via security) as in my experience they may abuse it to get content onto the site that they would normally be unable to.

Comment: the TBB you mention on World is here http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/useful_tbbs.aspx (it's #5: Get CSS Images) and I've written an explanation about the process in this answer before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433013/how-to-publish-image-folder-from-content-manager-using-c-sharp-tbb

Comment: Thanks Bart. At the time of writing my answer I was on my way out so I didn't have time to find it :)

Comment: No problem, just figured I'd add the link. One more comment I would like to make on it is that I would favor the process of the Schema and managing it as text. Since managing a text file as binary content is just wrong in my opinion.

Comment: Indeed. I happen to agree with you, but I wanted to give the option

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: when you say "hide this schema from editors (via security)" that's open to misinterpretation. If the templating emits verbatim content, you need to ensure that they can not use the schema to make a component. So for example, preventing navigation to the containing folder wouldn't be enough. I'm sure that's what you meant, but let's just be pedantic about it! :-)

Comment: Indeed, that is what I meant. Thanks for the elaboration

Comment: I think Dominic means removing `read` from the folder that has the schema can prevent authors from making components based on that schema. Less pendatry, more action-able steps! :-p

Comment: Here are those TBBs on the AppStore: https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/set-of-useful-template-building-blocks/688/